# Run a java function when leaving a page(HTML)

Tags: java, html

I'm making a program using Seam and Java. On my web page I have a form for the user to fill out. When I leave the page, however; the variables do not clear. Is there any way to run a java function from my bean when leaving the form page, or does anyone know a better way to go about doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Seam is a specialized version of Java Server Faces:

You can use the following scopes:

- Request : Use this scope for define your beans, because the variables will be disposed when the request is sent to the client.
- Session:Don't use this scope for store object and share between components because it can produce some memory problems
- Application: Use this just for objects shared across all the application and clientes.

I assume that you are using Session Scope, so my recommendation is that you use Request Scope.

Comment: It says that REQUEST doesn't exist

Comment: Since the scope of variables is not a trivial concept. I suggest that you read this: http://docs.jboss.com/seam/snapshot/en-US/html/concepts.html#d0e3564 before start to develop.